# Keep text smooth whilst animating

Tags: css, gsap

I am using the [Greensock library](http://greensock.com/gsap) to animate some text. It all works fine except that while the animation is progressing the characters become very pixelated. This effect disappears one the tween is complete.

I am trying to find a way to keep the text smooth throughout but can't make anything work. I have tried a bunch of suggestion from various sources - using `transform3d`, setting font smoothing, adding tiny shadows but with no success.

I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pr020mb/) that shows what I mean. If anyone can suggest a fix you would make me (and my manager) very happy :)

Thanks in advance internet.

PS - I don't know if it makes any difference but in my actual project I am using a Google web font rather than a system font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use font-size instead of size:

```
TweenLite.to("#txt", 3, {"font-size": "2em", transformOrigin:"50% 50%"});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pr020mb/3/)

Comment: That does do the job but the `transformOrigin works differently`. When using `scale` it resizes from the centre but using `font-size` it goes from the top left.